# As awesome as Meaning

Tags: meaning, adjective-phrases

What does this As  As usually means in sentences, just like in this sentence;

> **As awesome as** some of those shows with Jane  were, they were nothing compared to Green Day last night

I mean, does "as ... as" adds "even if/although" meaning in this sentence? What does speaker meand and highlight in the context?

Honestly, I am lost. I'd be really appreciated if you explain it. :)

Comment: Yes - there is indeed the implication of *even if/although* in the construction you're asking about here. That's to say it would mean *exactly* the same if we rephrased slightly to ***Despite** being as awesome as they [unquestionably] were, those shows were nothing compared to blah blah.* Or ***Even though** they were awesome, the were nothing compared to...*

Comment: Consider a simpler version of the same construction in [*As hungry as he was he could not (do something that might satisfy his hunger).*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22as+hungry+as+he+was+he+could+not%22) Which is equivalent to *Despite being (very) hungry, he couldn't blah blah*. The implication of *as [adj] as [noun] TO BE (is/was/are/etc.)* is that although *[noun]* is ***very** [adj]*, it's insufficiently so *for the specific current context.*

Comment: ...a typical usage: *As clever as he was, he couldn't answer the question*.

Comment: Might I ask one thing; Does speaker highlight "shows" only or "shows which /speaker/ attended with Jane" ... I mean does he talks about shows' being awesome, or they were awesome to him just because it was with Jane? --Very complicated question I know but I hope you understood me:)

Comment: Normally I'd expect the speaker to only really stress one of ***nothing, Green Day,*** or ***last night***. I can't imagine a context where the speaker would stress the word ***shows***, but he might feasibly stress ***some*** if he wanted to (pointedly) imply that *not all* of the shows with Jane were awesome, or ***Jane*** to imply something contextually relevant about her (such as the speaker thinking it would be *truly* awesome if Jane performed with Green Day perhaps; I don't know).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could rewrite it to say: Some of the shows with Jane were pretty awesome, but they . . . last night.

In the given sentence its use is similar to the Although A was B, blah C.